# One time gift intended to be recurring

Tags: civicontribute, contributions, recurring-contributions, iats

We recently had a donor give a one time gift that they intended to be a recurring gift. Hard to say if they neglected to click the box or if they did and something went awry. Regardless, what we are trying to correct now is that they would like the gift to occur monthly. Can I do something in the UI or in the database to turn this one time gift into a recurring gift, or is it best just to have the donor try again next month?  Thanks!

Drupal 7, Civi 4.6 LTS, iATS payment processing

Comment: Please note. This is a one time gift and not a recurring contribution. The format that is used is so nebulous and confusing that it is hard to understand exactly what is being asked. In the end, the contributor finds more funds are being taken from his/hers account than what was originally intended. Please clear up this matter. Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand your Answer - you seems to be contradicting the Question which says "they intended [it] to be a recurring gift" where as your Answer is saying "the contributor finds more funds are being taken from his/hers account than what was originally intended". If you have a different scenario then it would be better to ask your own Question and hopefully someone will have an answer for your situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the donor did **not** initiate the recurring contribution - then the extension did **not** tokenize the credit card - so you’ll need the card credentials from the donor to set up the recurring contribution.

Comment: is this answer missing a 'not'?

Comment: Yes it is!  - ok adding that